# Get laravel environment when running schedule

Tags: php, laravel, environment, schedule

I set up some commands in Laravel 5 schedule. The output is stored in the file and emailed to me.

Since there are several "copies" of the project I wanna use the environment name to be able to tell which copy the email came from.

I tried using `app()->environment()` in schedule description - it throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class env does not exist' in ...
```

I also tried `getenv('APP_ENV')` - this does not cause any error, but I get a blank environment name.

`App::environment()` didn't work either.

All of these work just fine if I use them in regular requests (for example controller actions or views).

Is there a way to determine current environment when running schedules?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

In my App\Console\Kernel schedule method, right before setting app all the schedules I added a line:

```
Dotenv::required('APP_ENV');
```

Keep in mind that you either have to `use Dotenv;` or add a \ to the line above because of the namespaces.

This way the system "makes sure" the APP_ENV is loaded and `app()->environment()` is returning correct environment name.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer doesn't work for Laravel 5.3 because `Dotenv`should not be called statically. Additionally it needs the path to the `.env` file as the first parameter.

You can use this instead (assumped you are inside `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`):

```
$env = new Dotenv(realpath(__DIR__.'/../../'.'.env'));
$env->required('APP_ENV');
```

Comment: Laravel helper `base_path()` would be preferable to all those dots.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the right way if you are using a recent version of Laravel (e.g. v9/v10)

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#environment-constraints

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')
        ->daily()
        ->environments(['staging', 'production']);
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way is to define the environment when calling the scheduler, e.g.:

```
php artisan schedule:run --env=local
```